# raise OSError('Not a gzipped file (%r)' % magic)　gzipのopenエラー

Tags: python, python3, gzip

書籍「ゼロから作るDeep Learning」の[サンプルコード](https://github.com/oreilly-japan/deep-learning-from-scratch/tree/master/dataset/mnist.py)を

```
$ python mnist.py
```

と実行すると，gzipの部分で以下のようなエラーが出ました．
なお、実行環境はAnaoconda3(python3.5), windows7です．

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user_name\Anaconda3\Lib\gzip.py", line 274, in read
    return self._buffer.read(size)
  File "C:\Users\user_name\Anaconda3\Lib\gzip.py", line 461, in read
    if not self._read_gzip_header():
  File "C:\Users\user_name\Anaconda3\Lib\gzip.py", line 409, in _read_gzip_header
    raise OSError('Not a gzipped file (%r)' % magic)
OSError: Not a gzipped file (b'<!')
```

エラーに関連すると思われる部分のコード(抜粋)は以下の`###`部分です．

```
def _load_label(file_name):
    file_path = dataset_dir + "/" + file_name    
    print("Converting " + file_name + " to NumPy Array ...")
    with gzip.open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
            labels = np.frombuffer(f.read(), np.uint8, offset=8) ###
    print("Done")
    return labels
```

どのように対応すればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: スクリプトに記述されたURLからファイルをダウンロードして開く部分でエラーとなっているようですが、「ファイルは保存されているか」「ファイルはgzファイルか」を念のため確認してみてください。

Comment: @cubickさん，ファイルはgzファイルとして保存はできています．

Comment: Macですが手元では動いています。一度*.gzを削除してもう一度試して見てください。ダウンロードされたファファイルは他のアーカイバーでは解凍できますか？Pythonのコードの問題ではない気がします。

Comment: 成功環境だけ報告。Windows 7 Pro 64bit 日本語版/Anaconda 3(conda 4.4.4)/Python 3.5.4で動作確認できました。コマンドプロンプトはWindows標準とAnaconda Prompt経由の両方で確認。文字コードは`chcp`で確認し`932`です。作業ディレクトリまでのパスに日本語や空白が含まれていても問題ありません。Anacondaやプロンプトのバージョン・環境変数に違いがないかチェックしてください

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi ,@dokubekoさん，コメントありがとうございます．先ほどDL済みの*.gzファイルを削除し，再度mnist.pyを実行したところ上手くいきました．DLしたファイルが破損していたようです．ご対応していただきありがとうございました．

Answer (score 1):

恐らくダウンロードしたファイルが破損していたのがエラーの原因だったようです。

`gz` ファイルをいったん削除し、再度 mnist.py を実行したところ上手くいきました。

---

*この投稿は [@sketch さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/40545/raise-oserrornot-a-gzipped-file-r-magic-gzip%e3%81%aeopen%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc#comment41218_40545) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*